# Couldn't import new files like .css .scss into sitecore using sxa creative exchange?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

I have exported site themes using export button on the home menu ribbon. I have added new sass component and run the gulp watch-component script, it converted .../sass/styles/component-xxx.scss file into .../styles/component-xxx.css file. I have added the new file reference into index.html file, themes successfully applied to my page locally.

I have zipped the local changes and tried to import that into Sitecore. It has thrown the below error.

```
An item name cannot contain any of the following characters: \/:?"<>|[]. (controlled by the setting InvalidItemNameChars)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemUtil.AssertItemName(Item destinationItem, String name)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Add(String name, TemplateID templateID)
   at Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase.CreateItemPath(String path, TemplateItem folderTemplate, TemplateItem itemTemplate)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Import.AssetProcessing.ContainerValidation.Process(AssetProcessingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.Import.Import.AssetEnumeration.ProcessAsset(IImportEntry entry, ImportArgs importArgs)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 collection, Action`1 action)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Jobs.Import.ImportBackgroundJob.Run(GetImportContextArgs args)
```

To resolve this error, I have manually created the component-xxx scss and css file in Sitecore under themes respective folder. Again I exported the themes zip file and applied my changes and imported that file into Sitecore. This time it imported successfully.

Is it the expected behavior of sxa that we couldn't add new files through creative exchange?

Comment: This is not expected behavior. I add new component files and zip it and import via creative exchange and it works. There must be some issue there, not sure though what this error is yet.

Comment: I get the same error, did you ever figure out the issue?